# Linq query in Entity Framework Core 3.5.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have tried every variation of this query in EF Core and I cannot figure it out.
I have simplified this as such:

**Invoice Table**

| InvoiceId | stuff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

**InvoiceLog Table**

| Id | InvoiceId | Date | PersonId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11/12/2015 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1/20/2018 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3/15/2019 | 3 |

**Person Table**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Steve |

Here's my question

```
var vm = (from i in _context.Invoice                      
                   join l in _context.InvoiceLog on i.InvoiceId equals l.InvoiceId
                  **//this is returning multiple records, how do I return only the one with the Min(Date)**

                  join pl in _context.Person on l.UpdateUserId equals pl.PersonId                     
                   select new InvoiceViewModel
                   {
                       InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,       
                       SubmitterName = pl.FirstName + " " + pl.LastName,
                   }).ToList();
```

ex> for Invoice 2 this should return ONE InvoiceLog record with the min date 1/20/2018 and the Person Name of Steve.

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .GroupJoin(
> outer: DbSet,
> inner: i => i.InvoiceId,
> outerKeySelector: l => l.InvoiceId,
> innerKeySelector: (i, lj) => new {
> i = i,
> lj = lj
> })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
> See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: EF Core version please. Also the entity model (especially the navigation properties).

Comment: I would recommend if you are trying to mix `AsEnumerable` with LINQ to EF (Core), switching to fluent/lambda syntax for your query. Also, EF Core only supports `into x` followed by `from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()` (LEFT JOIN). EF Core specifically does not support group join because there is no SQL equivalent, though you can build your own to emulate LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I am using EF Core 3.1.5.

Comment: NetMage - I added AsEnumerable() per some information I read re: that error message which seems to have something to do with EF Core and the way it handles client side parsing as opposed to earlier versions.  I'll revise the question.

Comment: @jodeenm by doing that you're loading the entire table in memory. The problem is using `Join` in the first place. EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. JOINS are generated based on the entity relations. If you really need to use Join, it means the relations are missing. The `InvoiceLog` entity should have an `Invoice` and `Person` property. Both `Person` and `Invoice` should have a `Logs` property

Comment: You haven't explained what you want either - a query isn't a question. You want all log entries with their invoice and persons? Or the first log per invoice? Or the first submitter per invoice?

Comment: I would like All Invoices and the EARLIEST SINGLE invoice log for each related invoice Id. I am able to join the tables fine, but unable to limit the Invoice Log to one record on MIN(Date).  I am getting multiple records....  I apologize if I am not explaining this well.

Comment: Your `Person` table seems to have some issues: 1. there is no record of `Id` of `3` to match `InvoiceLog` `Id` of `3`; 2. There is no `FirstName` and `LastName` column to match `pl.FirstName` and `pl.LastName`; 3. There is `PersonId` column to match `pl.PersonId` and your `InvoiceLog` has no `UpdateUserId` column to match `l.UpdateUserId`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `join`, you can use a cross-join by using `from` twice and filtering the second source down to the matching `InvoiceLog` rows and then taking the lowest one:

```
var vm = (from i in _context.Invoice
          from l in (from l2 in _context.InvoiceLog
                     where i.InvoiceId == l2.InvoiceId
                     orderby l2.Date
                     select l2).Take(1)
          join pl in _context.Person on l.UpdateUserId equals pl.Id
          select new InvoiceViewModel {
              InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
              SubmitterName = pl.Name
          }).ToList();
```

NOTE: EF Core 5 supports filtered include, with `OrderBy` and `Take`, so you could setup a proper relation between `Invoice` and `InvoiceLog` and then just `Include` what you need.